# calculating sharpe ratio in java

Tags: java, statistics

I am trying to calculate sharpe ratio in java, but I am struggling to find a "correct" dataset and result to test

Refering to http://www.hedgeco.net/blogs/2008/07/30/explaining-the-sharpe-ratio-again/

Investment Monthly Returns

```
Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May    June  Jul    Aug  Sep    Oct    Nov  Dec
1.64  5.85  9.22  3.51  -0.88  1.07  13.03  9.4  10.49  -5.08  n/a  n/a
```

Risk Free Rate 5%

However, I could not get what he got (2.56, instead I got 2.67 rounding error?)

Is this the right way (or commonly accepted way) to compute sharpe ratio?

My code (statistics computed using apache-commons-math)

```
    DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();
    for( double item : returns) {
        stats.addValue(item);
    }

    double mean = stats.getMean();

    double std = stats.getStandardDeviation();

    double sharpeRatio = (mean - (riskFreeReturn/12) ) / std * Math.sqrt(12);

    System.out.println("sharpeRatio="+ sharpeRatio);
```

Comment: First of all, Sharpe Ratio is yet another scam in the field of "econometrics". Secondly, are you sure that you are computing standard deviation correctly?

Comment: I am using apache.commons.math library to calculate std deviation. So I assume it's correct?

Comment: @Hamish - Sharpe Ratio is investments terminology, not econometrics.

Comment: I get 2.6568 -- you're both wrong.

Comment: Your calculation appears to assume you have 12 months worth of data when you only have 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the calculations](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p6ANaTAJHTuvyorB6Vx5RCw) the article links to, you have the right answer and the article displays the wrong results.

Comment: rule the DescriptiveStatistics class is using an unbiased estimtor (based on the comments on the Variance.java in commons-math package)

Comment: @portoalet - that's what I discovered, too, so I changed my answer.